# Why am I getting an "unused argument" error when using R database query params?

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi

I'm absolutely baffled by this bug that seems to have appeared. I need to use the `params` parameter in a database query, but every time I do, I get an "unused argument" error. I've checked the docs and even old code of mine that does the same thing and I can't tell what's going wrong now.

So for example, this works fine:

```
yearIdsQuery <- "SELECT * FROM dimTime WHERE year = 1975"
timeIds.df <- dbGetQuery(mysql_con, yearIdsQuery)
```

But this throws the error:

```
yearIdsQuery <- "SELECT * FROM dimTime WHERE year = ?"
timeIds.df <- dbGetQuery(mysql_con, yearIdsQuery, params = list(1975))
```

I'm running (I believe) R 4.2.2 and using the RMySQL library (which I believe itself uses the DBI library) to connect to a MySQL database on Amazon Web Services. I'm working in RStudio on an M1 Mac running Big Sur 11.6.

I would swear I've used identical code successfully in the last few days, but I'm quite new to R, so I'm not certain if I've done something wrong or there's an actual glitch occurring. I tried using dbExecute instead of dbGetQuery, and even tried dbBind/dbFetch, but I get the same error regardless. I've also tried making the element in the params list a string rather than a number.

Any insights or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT 1: Here's the entire error message.

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : unused argument (params = list(1975))

EDIT 2: The results of traceback():

```
5: dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
4: dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
3: .local(conn, statement, ...)
2: dbGetQuery(mysql_con, yearIdsQuery, params = list(1975))
1: dbGetQuery(mysql_con, yearIdsQuery, params = list(1975))
```

Comment: Please post the packages (libraries) you are using. In particular, make sure you are calling `dbGetQuery` from the package you think you are, and then check the man page carefully.    in addition   **always** post the exact error message you got.

Comment: I see a `dbGetQuery` listed in at least three libraries (via  `sos::???` operator).   You probably are using one you don't expect to be using

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've updated the question with the complete error message--sorry about that! As far as libraries, the only one I'm explicitly calling is RMySQL, which I believe loads DBI as a dependency. Is there a way to see all the packages that are loaded?

Comment: @jpsmith Did you intend to change the formatting of the second code block?

Comment: @NatWebb whoops, sorry! That was an accident - Corrected

Comment: try using  `traceback()`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Added the traceback() results!

Comment: Looks like whichever `dbGetQuery` is being invoked is passing all of its arguments to `.local` via the `...` mechanism.   Give us the result of `find("dbGetQuery")` so we can find out which package is actually in use.   Also,  `search()` will give you all loaded libraries, in execution (call) order